# Generator takes two values together instead of one by one

Tags: javascript, node.js, generator

I have a function that takes a promise and returns a generator function,
and a function that initializes the generator, that function returns a function to use that takes argument and pass it to the generator.
then the generator resolve the promise and returns the resolved value.
So when I try to use it asynchronous (for example in the browser console) it works but when I execute 2 at the same time and the second value comes out as null. the generator takes them together instead of one by one.

```js
const createWrapper = promise => {
  return async function*() {
    while (true) {
      const value = yield null // to get the parameter 
      try {
        const results = await promise(value)
        yield results
      } catch (error) {
        yield error
      }
    }
  }
}

const generator = promise => {
  const wrapper = createWrapper(promise)() // initializing the generator
  wrapper.next() // because it starts with null

  const next = async(value) => {
    const results = await wrapper.next(value) // returns the resolved value
    await wrapper.next() // because it starts with null
    return results
  }

  return {
    next
  }
}

const testPromise = (value) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(value)
  })
}

const test = generator(testPromise)

test.next('a').then(console.log) // outputs 'a'
test.next('b').then(console.log) // outputs null
test.next('c').then(console.log) // outputs 'c'
```

So it does works when I execute the test.next asynchronies but when I execute them together (like in the code above) they come to the generator together instead of one by one acts weird with the yield null and the second test.next comes null

I tried to see if the results are null so I call next again, but it didn’t work
And I console logged in the generator and saw it comes together
I expected to see it prints from the generator then from below like that 3 times
but it printed from the generator 3 times then from below 3 times
I also tried to check if the resolved value is null then to call next() again but it didn't work too